# MongoDB (PHP) - Custom "id", and OrderWith number

Tags: php, mongodb

First to say that I'm new to MongoDb and document oriented db's in general.

After some trouble with embedded documents in mongodb (unable to select only nested document (example single comment in blog post)), 
I redesigned the db. Now I have two collections, posts and comments (not the real deal, using blog example for convinience sake).

Example - posts collection document:

Array {

```
'_id'   :  MongoId,

'title' : 'Something',

'body'  : 'Something awesome'
```

}

Example - comments document:

Array {

```
'_id'    : MongoId,

'postId' : MongoId,

'userId' : MongoId,

'commentId' : 33,

'comment' : 'Punch the punch line!'
```

}

As you can see, I have multiple comment documents (As I said before, I want to be able to select single comment, and not an array of them).

My plan is this: I want to select single comment from collection using postId and commentId (commentId is unique value only among comments with the same postId).
Oh and commentId needs to be an int, so that I could be able to use that value for calculating next and previous documents, sort of "orderWith" number.

Now I can get a comment like this:

URI: mongo.php?post=4de526b67cdfa94f0f000000&comment=4

Code: $comment = $collection->findOne(array("postId" => $theObjId, "commentId" => (int)$commentId));

I have a few questions.

1. Am I doing it right?
2. What is the best way to generate that kind of commentId?
3. What is the best way to ensure that commentId is unique among comments with the same postId (upsert?)?
4. How to deal with concurrent queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I doing it right?

This is a really difficult question. Does it work? Does it meet your performance needs, are you comfortable maintaining it?

MongoDB doesn't have any notion of "normalization" or the "the one true way". You model your data in a way that works for you.

> What is the best way to generate that kind of commentId?
>   What is the best way to ensure that commentId is unique among comments with the same postId (upsert?)?

This is really a complex problem. If you want to generate monotonically increasing integers  IDs (like auto-increment), then you need a central authority for generating these integers. That doesn't tend to scale very well.

The commonly suggested method is to use the the ObjectId/MongoId. That will give you a unique ID.

However, you really want an integer. So take a look at [findAndModify](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command). You can keep a "last_comment_id" on your post and then update it when creating a new comment.

> How to deal with concurrent queries?

Why would concurrent queries be a problem? Two readers should be able to access the same data.

Are you worried about concurrent comments being created? Then see the find an modify docs.

Comment: @Gates and @Earlz
Thanks for your help, but at the end I'm going to use ref with MongoId.

Comment: Wow... I didn't know that comments have 5 minutes window for edit :(
Here is the rest of the previous one.
@Gates and @Earlz
Thanks for your help, but at the end I'm going to use ref with MongoId. Post document is going to have array of mongoids referencing comments in separate collection. Mongo's "auto incrementing" array keys will serve as integers. With that I suppose I'll be able to sort and select previous and next element.

Comment: Hm I didn't get the point why you store the comments in a separate collection. That doesn't make any sense from a doc-oriented (non-relational) point of view and somehow contradicts the idea behind mongodb's concept. Especially it doesn't make any sense to reference them by an array of MongoIds in your posts' collection, regarding the resulting loss of performance and a horrible maintaining orgy. Instead of wasting energy on further db redesigns... maybe it would be a good idea to propose another question concerning your "trouble" with embedding. I believe there are suitable solutions... ;)

Comment: @proximus
One of the biggest problems I'm having right know is the fact that mongodb is unable to select and return ONLY ONE embedded array/document from inside regular document;

Instead I need to get the whole document with embedded array, with atleast 500 elements (which aren't small simple comments btw.)

Anyway by the look of things, I'll be using mysql for now. Atleast until this https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-142 becomes available.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Marko Maybe I misundertstood your concern... but isn't the retrieval of single embedded arrays/documents covered by [this](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields) ? E. g. Your comments associated with a post are stored as an array _comments_ inside your post doc and each nested comment contains a unique key (e. g. an _ObjectId_ for sorting reasons), you could do a: `db.posts.findOne( { '_id' : ObjectId('...'), 'comments.id' : ObjectId('...') }, { comments : 1 } );` (note **{ comments : 1 }**, equal to `$fields` param in PHP's `MongoCollection::find()`)

Comment: @proximus: SERVER-142 may be fixed by the upcoming aggregation framework, please keep an eye out. Also, your "ONLY ONE" statement is not correct. MongoDB is not very good a retrieving a single element from an array. However, MongoDB is completely capable of retrieving one embedded document. Store your comments as an embedded document and you can reasonably return `"comments.1"`. It's really about how you structure your data.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if The Big Picture will allow you to do this, but here is how I'd do it.

I'd have an array of comments contained inside each post. This means no joins are needed. In your case, normalization of comments doesn't give any benefit. I'd replace `CommentID` with `CreatedAt` as the time of creation.

This will let you have an easy data model to work with, as well as the ability to sort it.